# my UIswitch value is nil even when its on I have to turn swich off and then back on for it to set value

Tags: swift, uiswitch

using UIswitch to set value 
my variable is static because im using them in diffrent swift file 
so when I run program and click registration button it prints nil 
even tho its on (button stays the way it was left when closing app)
I have to toggle it and then click registration button for it to print optional(true)
what can i do so user dont have to togggle everytime  they open app or when it shows on when app opened but value is nil 
also I just want it to print true/false (how do i unwrap)

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    static var FirstColor: Bool!

    @IBAction func home(_ sender: RoundButton) {
    }
    @IBAction func Registration(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        print(FirstViewController.FirstColor)
    }

    @IBAction func ColorSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn{
            FirstViewController.FirstColor = true
        }else{FirstViewController.FirstColor = false }
    }
}
```

Comment: please consider using periods in the texts you write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to persist the switch status you need to store it in UserDefaults. Don't add a static property in FirstViewController. Create a separate class like this with a computed property

```
class Color {
    static var firstColor: Bool {
        get { return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "firstColor") }
        set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "firstColor") }
    }
}
```

In FirstViewController's viewDidLoad get last status and update

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mySwitch.isOn = Color.firstColor
}
```

In Switch's action change it

```
@IBAction func ColorSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    sender.isOn = !sender.isOn
    Color.firstColor = sender.isOn
}
```

Comment: nope still nil is that how apple default is ?
also whenever I run app the switches load with on even tho i turned them off when i stopped app

Comment: You have to persist the status when closing the app. Have a look at the UserDefaults class (specifically the set and the bool func).

Comment: @kishan You didn't store the staus of the switch anywhere when closing the app

Comment: @kishan In FirstViewController's viewDidLoad you need to get persisted value and change Switch according to that.

Comment: yeah i think this should work I dint know a way to set status when closing app thx

Comment: Missing return in a function expected to return 'Bool'
for class color

Comment: ur genius 
get { let RandomColor = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "firstColor")
            return RandomColor
that was fix

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the value of the isOn property directly. Does this help? Also I suggest that you use better names for your handlers.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    static var FirstColor: Bool!

    @IBAction func registrationTapped(_ sender: RoundButton)
    {
        print(FirstViewController.FirstColor)
    }

    @IBAction func colorChanged(_ sender: UISwitch)
    {
        FirstViewController.FirstColor = sender.isOn
    }
}
```

Comment: same button loads with on 
i dont touch buttons as soon as i registration button value prints nil 
so since button loads as on do you know how to load as off everytime opens app and i'll just set static var FirstColor: Bool! to false